# Unity 2D - No movement on empty background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game in unity. The game generates room prefabs like dungeons. The room walls have collider so the player can't escape the room. However there are still some ways to espace from the rooms.

So my question is: can you make it that the player can only move on rooms which it generates and not allow movement on the empty background? Something like the collider which will block movement on empty camera background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layer for moveable locations.

[image: Create Layer]

---

For the created rooms, put collider 2d as below and specify their layer.

[image: Generated Room Area]

Then, like the code below, determine that the character can only move in the defined places.

```cs
[SerializeField] private LayerMask movableLayer;
void Update()
{
    if (Physics2D.OverlapPoint(transform.position, movableLayer))
    {
        Debug.Log("<color=#51FF56>Character can move here..</color>");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("<color=#FF3854>Character can't move here </color>");
    }
}
```

[image: Movement Script]

---

### Limit to Room box

---

To solve the problem of limiting the character to bounds, it is enough to add the collider check point to the movement axis so that it checks a little further. Here, according to the dimensions of the character, I considered the coefficient .5f.

```cs
[SerializeField] private LayerMask movableLayer;

private Vector3 inputVector;

void Update()
{
    inputVector.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    inputVector.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position+inputVector*.5f, transform.position, Color.cyan);
    
    if (Physics2D.OverlapPoint(transform.position+inputVector*.5f, movableLayer.value))
    {
        transform.position += inputVector * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

[image: Box Test]

Comment: Where should the script be? In every room?

Comment: @Por5as your character

Comment: I tried it today. It works fine, it's nice, but is there a way to not even allow player go outside of the rooms?

Comment: @Por5as Place colliders in any part that can be moved. In the else part, you can write the special movement outside the frame, but your question is specifically to limit the movement and it contradicts your new question. Anyway, if the answer helped you, you can put the green tick and raise another problem in the new question. Thank you.

Comment: And what about if player leaves the "movable" layer that it will stop him from moving (maybe just disable movement script) and teleport him to place where he left the rooms from?

Comment: @Por5as I figured out what the problem was and updated the answer. I hope it fixes the problem.

Comment: Hello, I tried the code, but it doesn't work. There is no error shown, but it does nothing. (I assigned layer and put script into the player)